# Lazarus - Mac OSX Debugging Error

Tags: macos, compilation, lazarus

I used to use Delphi 7 on my PC, but now that I bought a MacBook (Mid 2012 - OSX Mountain Lion), I wanted to continue programming in Pascal and have a similar Interface. Lazarus seems to deliver most of the things I wanted, but it seems to run into a lot of errors, when compiling even the simplest applications! To test it, I made a simple "Russian Roulette" application, just for fun, but the program just freezes, when launched or even when compiled inside Lazarus.
When launching it from command line, It shows me the following error:

```
TCarbonButton.SetFocus Error: SetKeyboardFocus  failed with result -30585
```

I don't think my coding is the problem, but I guess I should include it:

```
unit RussianRouletteUnit;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls,
  Buttons, ExtCtrls;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Kugeln: TLabeledEdit;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Number: Integer;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Random(StrToInt(Kugeln.Text))+1 = 1 then
     begin
          Button1.SetFocus;
          Memo1.Color := clred;
          Memo1.Text := 'BOOM';
          Memo1.Lines.Add('HEADSHOT');
     end;
end;

initialization
randomize;
end.
```

I hope you guys can help me out, any help is apprechiated :D

Comment: Does the problem occur for all versions of Lazarus/FPC?

Comment: here you can find info about MacOSX widgets focusing: (http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Carbon_interface_internals#Focusing), and (http://bugs.freepascal.org/view.php?id=23276)

Comment: Why do you set focus to Button1 that has just been clicked? What happens if you comment that line?

Comment: Please do not tag purely-lazarus questions as Delphi.